# PHP retorna NULL quando informações tem acentos

Tags: php, mysql, json

Quando quero exibir os dados retornados por um JSON, ele me retorna *NULL*. Só que quando as informações do banco de dados estão sem acentos, ele me retorna normalmente:

```
<?php
include_once 'WSAps_conexao.php';

$cidade =$_POST['cidade'];

$sql = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM parques WHERE Cidade = '$cidade'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        $res[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($res);
}
else
{
    echo "login_false";
        }

?>
```

Comment: Provavelmente o seu banco de dados não deve estar codificado com caracteres UTF8, tente assim: `json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` e me diz se aparece alguma coisa quando você tenta retornar com os acentos.

Comment: Ainda esta me retornando NULL, meu Banco de dados esta configurado com utf8_general_ci

Comment: Tente usar o set_charset('utf8') também como a resposta do Guilherme, precisa verificar se o seu arquivo em PHP também está em UTF8, e se o arquivo que envia as informações para seu banco de dados, também esteja na mesma codificação. Se vc utilizar o software notepad++, no menu `Formatar`, tem como você verificar se o documento está na codificação certa. É bom verificar todos os lugares por onde passa as informações se está na mesma codificação.

Comment: http://rmonte.com/acentuacao-no-php-e-mysql-com-utf-8/

Nesse link explica um pouco sobre o q estou falando, os comandos estão em MySql, mas é facil mudar pra MySQLi. Nos comentários tem um exemplo: http://rmonte.com/acentuacao-no-php-e-mysql-com-utf-8/#comment-1895

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, consegui pelo set_charset('utf8'), conforme a resposta do Guilherme

Comment: @FernandoVR só necessita os arquivos serem salvos em utf8 e o header/charset se os acentos não forem escapados no json_encode, mas como por padrão ele "escapa", por exemplo "ã" vira "\u00e3" então não há necesside, e no momento que usar no Android (caso do autor) ele provavelmente irá usar `JSONobject` (https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), o que irá reconhecer os acentos escapados e irá imprimir normalmente.

Comment: Eu entendo @GuilhermeNascimento, mas por incrível que pareça ja tive problemas também com acentuação quando o arquivo que enviava para o banco de dados, estar em codificação diferente. Ele enviava para o banco de dados numa codificação que o banco de dados salvava em outra e na hora de exibir a consulta tava um resultado diferente. Como não conheço o sistema do amigo que perguntou, então as vezes é bom verificar todo o caminho de informações até achar aonde está o erro.

Comment: Que bom @PatrickCamargo que deu tudo certo. Abraços ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque o JSON encode só suporta UTF-8 e provavelmente o seu banco esta em latin1, você pode trocar a codificação assim:

```
//Salva o charset padrão (só é necessário se for usar a conexão para outra coisa)
$charsetAnterior = db->get_charset()->charset;

//Define o charset para utf8
if (false === $mysqli->set_charset('utf8')) {
    printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', $mysqli->error);
    exit;
}

$sql = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM parques WHERE Cidade = '$cidade'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        $res[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($res);
} else {
    echo "login_false";
}

//Restaura o charset
if (false === $mysqli->set_charset($charsetAnterior)) {
    printf('Error ao usar %s: %s', $charsetAnterior, $mysqli->error);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Fiz a alteração no código, mas ele me retorna "Parque de S\u00e3o Paulo" ao invés de "Parque de São Paulo".

Comment: @PatrickCamargo Sim, isso esta correto, acentos em JSON ficam neste formato para evitar perda de caracteres na transmissão, isso é feito pelo proprio JSON_ENCODE e não pelo set_charset. Mas se exibir o JSON em um Modal no seu aplicativo android vai notar que o acento irá aparecer corretamente.

Comment: Obrigado cara, estava testando pelo navegador. Testei pelo App android e funcionou, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O php retorna corretamente, o json_encode que transforma em null pois não está em utf-8. Aqui tem outra solução:

Antes de retornar você chama uma função para converter o array em utf-8

```
$result = converteArrayParaUtf8($result); //chama a função
return json_encode($result); //retorna
```

função:

```
function converteArrayParaUtf8($result){
    array_walk_recursive($result, function(&$item,$key){
         if (!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)) {
                $item = utf8_encode($item);
            }
    });
    return $result;
}
```